# jhipster ionic4 generated app can't authenticate to keycloak following article"How to Use Ionic 4 for JHipster 6 to Build a Mobile App"

Tags: ionic4, jhipster, keycloak, spring-security-oauth2

I was following the great article [How to Use Ionic 4 for JHipster 6 to Build a Mobile App](https://dzone.com/articles/learn-how-to-use-iconic-4-for-jhipster-6-to-build), and want to stay on Keycloak as a identity provider (for now :) )
I follow the article and pass successfully the generating, running and authenticate to app with built in credentials admin/admin.

At the second step I generated and run ionic app and typed:

```
cd mobile
ionic serve
```

and I got my mobile app running with login screen.
I typed again admin/admin and got folowing outhput in my backend app console:

```
2020-05-16 16:19:08.094  WARN 12590 --- [ XNIO-1 task-56] o.z.problem.spring.common.AdviceTraits   : Forbidden: Could not verify the provided CSRF token because your session was not found.
2020-05-16 16:19:08.097  WARN 12590 --- [ XNIO-1 task-56] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.security.web.csrf.MissingCsrfTokenException: Could not verify the provided CSRF token because your session was not found.]
```

And of course i can't login to mobile app. I did not change anything related to Octa things (because it is Octa specific)

How can I enable and successfully log in to generated Ionic4 mobile app using Keycloak instead of Octa identity provider?

Comment: Ionic for JHipster should work with Keycloak by default. You might try watching the video from the original article. https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/06/24/ionic-4-angular-spring-boot-jhipster

Comment: Thanks, I did it but stack on another step. When i generate app with yo jhipster-ionic I successfully run mobile app but when i add yo jhipster-ionic:entity album, and run again I get [ng] ERROR in Cannot read property 'loadChildren' of undefined
(btw ionic4j commnad does not work) In browser when i point to http://localhost:8100/ have blank screen with Cannot GET /

Comment: What version of Ionic for JHipster are you using?

Comment: Thanks, I updated everything to newest, and all was passed, and I successfully run Android app! Only thing I can't use is ionic4j shortcut, I need to use yo jhipster-ionic .... for entity generation. Any idea?

Comment: I'm not sure. I wrote it and the last time I tried, it didn't work either.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I just read your mini-book and i am exciting about it. We will talk soon about some issues I know ;)